# Как правильно использовать INotifyPropertyChanged для извещения "родителя" о изменение экземпляра?

Tags: c#

Проблема такая: необходимо изменять значения в коллекции при изменении хотя бы одного из полей в объекте. Если ближе к самой идеи кода, то при изменении длины одного из участков трубы, нужно пересчитать другие.

Архитектура в коде такая: родительский абстрактный класс `public abstract class AbstractTube`, от которого наследуется класс `public class TubingStage : AbstractTube`, и создается лист из труб

```
 public class CollectionTubingStage: ObservableCollection < TubingStage > ,
 INotifyPropertyChanged {}

 //Есть обработчик события и само событие в классе TubingStage:

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info) {
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
 }

 // И код свойства в том же классе

 public override double Lenght {
    get {
        return TLenght;
    }
    set {
        TLenght = value;
        NeedAutoAlign = true;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Lenght of stage has been changed!");
    }
 }
```

Как мне правильно воспользоваться `INotifyPropertyChanged` для этого? Не понятно как из экземпляра коллекции получить доступ к самой коллекции, для ее модификации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не-не, это не дело элемента коллекции, менять саму коллекцию.

Делайте так:

1. Участок трубы реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`
2. Класс `Tube` содержит приватно коллекцию участков. Он же занимается добавлением и удалением этих самых участков. `ObservableCollection` вообще не нужен, труба знает, когда в ней добавляются/уходят куски.
3. При добавлении куска труба подписывается на его `PropertyChanged`, при удалении отписывается
4. На `PropertyChanged` нужно пересчитать общую длину. Так же как и на добавлении и удалении куска.
5. Если сильно хочется, можно закешировать длины кусков, чтобы не опрашивать их повторно при изменении лишь одного куска. А можно и не делать, оптимизация не особо большая, больше мороки, чем пользы.

Comment: спасибо, но не все понятно до сих пор, думаю в отдельный вопрос надо вынести.